# Entity Framework and LINQ: Is there anyway to auto reflect the renamed entity in LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, orm, .net-3.5, ado.net-entity-data-model

I was trying to change the table names in the entity model or database but the old names are already use in many places in the application. Is there any way to auto reflect renamed entities or tables in the LINQ query or code.

Let say I have tables tblDepartment, tblEmployee and tblEmployeeDepartment. These tables are used in the code(LINQ) on many places. I like to change these tables names to Department, Employee and EmployeeDepartment. So, is there anyway to auto reflect name in LINQ or code when I change table names either using Database First or Model First approach.

P.S. The application is based on .Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

**Working With linq and Entity Framework plus excel reports|Enjoy**

```
    public static string strMessage = "";
    public SchoolEntities dbContext;

    public string login(string strUsername, string strPassword)
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        var linqQuery = from User in dbContext.People
                        where User.FirstName == strUsername && User.LastName == strPassword
                        select User;

        if (linqQuery.Count() == 1)
        {
            strMessage = "Good";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "Bad";
        }

        return strMessage;

    }
    public Object LoadPersonDetails()
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        //DataTable dtPerson = new DataTable();

        var linqQuery = from users in dbContext.People
                        select users;

        //List<Person> Users = linqQuery.ToList();

        //dtPerson = linqQuery.ToList();

        return linqQuery;
    }

    public void InsertPerson(string strLName, string strFName, string strHireDate, string EnrollmentDate)
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();
        Person NewPerson = dbContext.People.Create();

        NewPerson.LastName = strLName;
        NewPerson.FirstName = strFName;
        NewPerson.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strHireDate);
        NewPerson.EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EnrollmentDate);

        dbContext.People.Add(NewPerson);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void DeleteUser(int intPersonID)
    {
        //dbContext = new SchoolEntities();
        using (dbContext = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            Person Person = dbContext.People.Where(c => c.PersonID == intPersonID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Person != null)
            {
                dbContext.People.Remove(Person);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ModifyPerson(int intPersonID, string strLName, string strFName, string strHireDate, string EnrollmentDate)
    {
        var UpdatePerson = dbContext.People.FirstOrDefault(s => s.PersonID == intPersonID);

        UpdatePerson.LastName = strLName;
        UpdatePerson.FirstName = strFName;
        UpdatePerson.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strHireDate);
        UpdatePerson.EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EnrollmentDate);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    private Excel.Application XApp = null; //Creates the Excel Document
    private Excel.Workbook XWorkbook = null; //create the workbook in the recently created document
    private Excel.Worksheet XWorksheet = null; //allows us to work with current worksheet
    private Excel.Range XWorkSheet_range = null; // allows us to modify cells on the sheet

    public void Reports()
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        var linqQuery = (from users in dbContext.StudentGrades
                         group users by new { users.EnrollmentID, users.CourseID, users.StudentID, users.Grade }
                         into UserGroup
                         orderby UserGroup.Key.CourseID ascending
                         select new { UserGroup.Key.EnrollmentID, UserGroup.Key.CourseID, UserGroup.Key.StudentID, UserGroup.Key.Grade }).ToList();

        var RatingAverage = dbContext.StudentGrades.Average(r => r.Grade);

        var GradeSum = dbContext.StudentGrades.Sum(r => r.Grade);

        /*var linqQuery = (from users in dbContext.StudentGrades
                         orderby users.CourseID descending
                         select users).ToList();*/

        //Array Motho = linqQuery.ToArray();

        XApp = new Excel.Application();
        XApp.Visible = true;
        XWorkbook = XApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        XWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XWorkbook.Sheets[1]; 

        //Create column headers
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "EnrollmentID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 2] = "CourseID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 3] = "StudentID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Grade";
        //XWorksheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Enrollment Date";

        int row = 3;

        foreach (var Mothos in linqQuery)
        {
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 1] = Mothos.EnrollmentID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 2] = Mothos.CourseID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 3] = Mothos.StudentID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 4] = Mothos.Grade.ToString();

            row++;
        }

        int rows = linqQuery.Count();

        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 4, 3] = "Grades Average";
        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 4, 4] = RatingAverage.Value.ToString();

        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 5, 3] = "Grades Sum";
        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 5, 4] = GradeSum.Value.ToString();

        //XWorkSheet_range.ColumnWidth = 30;

        //XWorksheet.Cells.AutoFit();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's a lot of code, would you care to explain it a little so it's more useful to others?

Answer (score 0):

## Working with edm and Excel-grouped report

---

```
public void Function_Create_Sales()
        { 
        
        DBContext = new PubsEntities();

        var linqStores = from Sales in DBContext.sales
                         orderby Sales.stor_id
                         select Sales;

        var lstStore = linqStores.ToList();

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets[1];

        int GroupTotal = 0;
        int GrandTotal = 0;
        int ExcelRow = 5;
        string intTemp = lstStore[0].stor_id;
        xlSheet.Cells[4, 1] = lstStore[0].stor_id;

        //Create column headers
        xlSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sales Grouped By Store";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Group header";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Store ID";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "Order Number";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "Order Date";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "Quantity";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 6] = "payments";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 7] = "title ID";

        for (int count = 0; count < lstStore.Count; count++)
        {
            if (intTemp == lstStore[count].stor_id)
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 2] = lstStore[count].stor_id.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 3] = lstStore[count].ord_date.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 4] = lstStore[count].qty.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = lstStore[count].payterms.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = lstStore[count].title_id.ToString();

                ExcelRow++;
                GroupTotal++;
                GrandTotal++;
            }
            else
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Total for: " + intTemp + " = " + GroupTotal.ToString();
                ExcelRow++;
                intTemp = lstStore[count].stor_id;
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 1] = lstStore[count].stor_id;
                count--;
                GroupTotal = 0;
                ExcelRow++;
            }
        }
        xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Total for: " + intTemp + " = " + GroupTotal.ToString();
        ExcelRow++;
        xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Grand Total = " + GrandTotal.ToString();

        xlSheet.Rows.Columns.AutoFit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working with xml | add, modify and delete xml data**

```
    string conn = "E:/School/Development Sftware/2014/ReadWriteUpdateDeleteXML/DataService/Profiles.xml";
    public string InsertProfile(string fname, string lname, string phone, string gender)
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(conn);
        XmlElement subRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Profile");

        //add first name
        XmlElement appendedElementFname = xmlDoc.CreateElement("FirstName");
        XmlText xmlTextFname = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(fname.Trim());
        appendedElementFname.AppendChild(xmlTextFname);
        subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementFname);
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

        //add last name
        XmlElement appendedElementLname = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LastName");
        XmlText xmlTextLname = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(lname.Trim());
        appendedElementLname.AppendChild(xmlTextLname);
        subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementLname);
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

        //add phone
        XmlElement appendedElementPhone = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Phone");
        XmlText xmlTextPhone = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(phone.Trim());
        appendedElementPhone.AppendChild(xmlTextPhone);
        subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementPhone);
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

        //add gender
        XmlElement appendedElementGender = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Gender");
        XmlText xmlTextGender = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(gender.Trim());
        appendedElementGender.AppendChild(xmlTextGender);
        subRoot.AppendChild(appendedElementGender);
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(subRoot);

        xmlDoc.Save(conn);

        return "Profile Saved";
    }
    public DataSet LoadXML()
    {
        DataSet dsLog = new DataSet();
        dsLog.ReadXml(conn);
        return dsLog;
    }
    public string DeleteProfile(string fname)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(conn);

        //XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Profiles/Profile[@FirstName=" + fname + "]");
        //if (nodeToDelete != null)
        //{
        //    nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
        //}
        //xmlDoc.Save("C:/Users/Shazzy/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ReadWriteUpdateDeleteXML/DataService/Profiles.xml");
        //return "Deleted";

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Profiles/Profile"))
        {
            if (node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText == fname)
            {
                node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
            }

        }
        xmlDoc.Save(conn);

        return "Deleted";
    }
    public string ModifyProfile(string fname, string lname, string phone, string gender)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(conn);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Profiles/Profile"))
        {
            if (node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText == fname)
            {
                node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText = fname;
                node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText = lname;
                node.SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText = phone;
                node.SelectSingleNode("Gender").InnerText = gender;
            }
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(conn);

        return "Updated";
    }
```